# Test Class on an Update Trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, before-trigger

This is my very first trigger. It does exactly what I intended it to do.

```
trigger FirmAssociationTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(Opportunity a : Trigger.new) {
        // Get the before change values
        Opportunity oldFirmValue  = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
        
        // Compare Consulting_Firm__c
        if(a.Consulting_Firm__c  != oldFirmValue.Consulting_Firm__c) {
            a.Firm_Association__c = null;
        }
        
        // Compare AccountID
        if(a.AccountId != oldFirmValue.AccountID) {
            a.Firm_Association__c = null;
        }

        //Compare Primary_Consultant_Name__c
        if(a.Primary_Consultant_Name__c != oldFirmValue.Primary_Consultant_Name__c) {
            a.Firm_Association__c = null;
        }
    } 
}
```

All four fields (including the field I need to wipe at the end) are lookup fields. Took a while to figure out how to handle this, but I did finally figure out how to do lookups. So this is my very first test class.

```
@isTest
public class FirmAssociationTriggerTest {

    @isTest static void wipeFirmAssociation() {
        // Populate Lookup Account Data
        Account clientFirmAccount = new Account();
            clientFirmAccount.Name = 'Client Firm';
            insert clientFirmAccount;
            
        Account consultingFirmAccount = new Account();
            consultingFirmAccount.Name = 'Consultant Firm';
            insert consultingFirmAccount;
        
        Contact consultantContact = new Contact();
            consultantContact.FirstName = 'Test';
            consultantContact.LastName = 'Contact';
            insert consultantContact;                
            
        Account clientFirmAccount1 = new Account();
            clientFirmAccount1.Name = 'Client Firm1';
            insert clientFirmAccount1;
            
        Account consultingFirmAccount1 = new Account();
            consultingFirmAccount1.Name = 'Consultant Firm1';
            insert consultingFirmAccount1;
        
        Contact consultantContact1 = new Contact();
            consultantContact1.FirstName = 'Test1';
            consultantContact1.LastName = 'Contact1';
            insert consultantContact1;              
        
        // Create an Opportunity and Set Required fields
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.AccountID = clientFirmAccount.Id;
        opp.Consulting_Firm__c = consultingFirmAccount.Id;
        opp.Primary_Consultant_Name__c = consultantContact.Id;
        opp.StageName = 'Developmental';
        opp.CloseDate = System.today();
        insert opp;
        
        opp.Consulting_Firm__c = consultingFirmAccount1.Id;
        update opp;

    }
}
```

So far this is what I have... not intended it to be perfect, but wanted to see at least some coverage. However, I am getting 0% Test coverage :'( Trying very hard to learn to make my first trigger work. I do need to push this into production as this works in conjunction with a very complex flow I wrote. Can someone help me?

Comment: does the testmethod fail on the `insert opp` statement (or earlier)? That is the only way the `update opp` would never execute and give you 0% test coverage

Comment: Just as a side note, you may want to consider using an "else if" statement or grouping your if statements into one if statement using the Logical OR (||) .They way it is written now each if statement is being checked even if the previous one was already true. That's not needed as each statement is setting the a.Firm_Association__c to null.

Comment: Hi everyone! I actually ended up not needing this trigger after all, but still appreciate your help!